# Stripe Sources sofort or giropay return url

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement payment via Stripe Source (Sofort and Giropay). Everything works fine, except one point:

A user is redirected to the Sofort-Servers. When everything works fine and the user pays the money, he gets redirected to redirect[return_url] as expected. But if the user doesn't pay (for example he has no valid bankdata, or just cancels the payment), he also gets redirected to redirect[return_url].

The problem is, that I dont know at this point, if the payment was successfull or not. So I dont know what to show the user: Payment successfull or redirect to checkout page.

Comment: Brother I need some direction to implement Sofort. I need sample code if it is possible to you. It will be highly appreciated if you'd post an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558425/need-some-direction-to-implement-sofort-a-payment-gateway-using-stripe-in-andr/62558746#62558746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after contacting the support I found out that the right way to do it is the following:

The user gets redirected to you redirect[return_url], including the token from stripe. There you can check on your server, what the status of the payment is and show the user the right message