# Need some direction to implement Sofort (a payment gateway) using Stripe in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm implementing **Sofort** payment gateway in Android by the help of **Stripe** and I need some direction. I'm following [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sofort)

I've successfully done till Step 2 but I'm not understanding how to go with [Point 3](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sofort#charge-request) to ***Charge the Source*** & ***webhooks***. Will there be some backend coding to implement webhooks?

If someone has already implemented **Sofort** please post it. I'll be very thankful. Please I need attention on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to do Steps 3 and 4 on the back end. You would pass the Source's 'id' to your backend server and start with the example code in Step 3:

https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sofort#make-a-charge-request-using-the-source

Then in Step 4 you implements a Webhook Endpoint that listens for the updated events:

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks